# Convert IP address string to binary in Python

Tags: python, binary, ip

As part of a larger application, I am trying to convert an IP address to binary. Purpose being to later calculate the broadcast address for Wake on LAN traffic. I am assuming that there is a much more efficient way to do this then the way I am thinking. Which is breaking up the IP address by octet, adding 0's to the beginning of each octet where necessary, converting each octet to binary, then combining the results. Should I be looking at netaddr, sockets, or something completely different?

Example: From 192.168.1.1 to 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001

Comment: Are you looking to convert an IPv4 Address into its integer representation? Or what binary representation are you trying to convert to?

Comment: Example:
From 192.168.1.1 to 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001

Comment: That is an extremely uncommon way to express ipaddresses. I don't think any module exists to produce or consume that format.

Comment: The way you are thinking of is perfectly good and efficient enough, IMHO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You think of something like below ?

```
ip = '192.168.1.1'
print '.'.join([bin(int(x)+256)[3:] for x in ip.split('.')])
```

I agree with others, you probably should avoid to convert to binary representation to achieve what you want.

Comment: That's what I was looking for but, I don't fully understand how it works. I get that you are splitting the ip address by '.', then joining the results by a '.', and converting from a integer to binary but this: "(x)+256)[3:] for x in", completely lost. Can you point in the right direction to look up what you are doing?

Comment: @pizzim13: no magick. You understood well how it works. The +256 is there to always have a 9 bits binary number, then it's easy to remove 0b1 at front of the number.

Comment: @pizzim13: and for the `[... for x in ... ]` part look at **list comprehension** in python documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Is [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html).`inet_aton()` what you want?

Comment: It seems to work: `bin(struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton('192.168.1.1'))[0])` -> `'0b11000000101010000000000100000001'`

Answer (score 8):

> Purpose being to later calculate the broadcast address for Wake on LAN traffic

[`ipaddr`](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) (see [PEP 3144](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3144/)):

```
import ipaddr

print ipaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.1.1/24').broadcast
# -> 192.168.1.255
```

In Python 3.3, [`ipaddress` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ipaddress

print(ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.162.1.1/24', strict=False).broadcast_address)
# -> 192.168.1.255
```

To match the example in your question exactly:

```
# convert ip string to a binary number
print(bin(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.1.1'))))
# -> 0b11000000101010000000000100000001
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use string format function to convert the numbers to binary. I made this function:

```
def ip2bin(ip):
    octets = map(int, ip.split('/')[0].split('.')) # '1.2.3.4'=>[1, 2, 3, 4]
    binary = '{0:08b}{1:08b}{2:08b}{3:08b}'.format(*octets)
    range = int(ip.split('/')[1]) if '/' in ip else None
    return binary[:range] if range else binary
```

This will return a binary IP or IP range, so you can use it to test if an IP is in a range:

```py
>>> ip2bin('255.255.127.0')
'11111111111111110111111100000000'
>>> ip2bin('255.255.127.0/24')
'111111111111111101111111'
>>> ip2bin('255.255.127.123').startswith(ip2bin('255.255.127.0/24'))
True
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Define IP address in variable

```
ipadd = "10.10.20.20"
```

convert IP address in list

```
ip = ipadd.split(".")
```

Now convert IP address in binary numbers

```
print ('{0:08b}.{1:08b}.{2:08b}. 
    {3:08b}'.format(int(ip[0]),int(ip[1]),int(ip[2]),int(ip[3])))

00001010.00001010.00010100.00010100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IP = '192.168.1.1'

ip2bin =  ".".join(map(str,["{0:08b}".format(int(x)) for x in IP.split(".")]))
print(ip2bin)
```

**output**

```
11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be looking at netaddr, sockets, or something completely different?

For anyone asking in the present day, you should use `netaddr` if you want to do anything not supported in the Python 3.3+ built-in `ipaddress` module. Here is how you would do what you wanted to with `netaddr`, as an example:

```
>>> from netaddr import IPAddress
>>> ip = IPAddress('192.168.1.1')
>>> print(ip.bits())
11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

ip = '192.168.1.1'

k=[" "]

for x in ip.split("."):

```
   a=(bin(int(x))[2:])
   k.append(a)
```

print(".".join(list(k))[2:])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).